# how to pip install in spyder 5

Tags: python, pip, spyder

I have Spyder 5 installed - I used to use pip install from the ipython console, however it looks like they disabled this. What's the best way for me to install packages on a Windows machine now if I have Spyder5 but not Anaconda?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Did you use or Windows or Mac installers to install Spyder?

Comment: @FObersteiner I think the question was the other way around: if you install Spyder 5 with the default installer from the Spyder website, `pip` doesn't seem to be installed with it

Comment: @Bruno right, I think that's basically described [in the FAQ](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-packages-installer).